# Why doesn't bootstrap modal display an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

when I tried using modal to display image from my folder,it doesn't load. However when I use placeholder.com to display an image from there, its getting loaded. The image is of exact same pixels, still its not loading in my browser. However its in the same exact folder and its showing in my editor .

This is my code for modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="detail-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detail-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="detail-1">Casuals - Blue
        </h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="pic1modal.png" alt="Casuals - blue"> </img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <h4> Details </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p>This deal is for a limited time so you cannot add to your cart
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
            BUY NOW
         </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the image i am trying to put in the modal

[image: This is the image i am trying to put in the modal]

This is how its appearing in my browser

[image: This is how its appearing in my browser]

Comment: please tell me which folder have image and where you have this modal?

Comment: Please check the source of image `<img class="img-responsive" src="pic1modal.png" alt="Casuals - blue"> </img>`. The image path seems to be incorrect as the inspector in your snapshot is complaining about not finding the image. It is not at `https://localhost/foot/pic1model.png`

Comment: i got it,so the pic was in my modal.php,bt the img src i had to give with respect to my mainpage